# New lines with tinymce editor, issue when decode in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce, json

I am using tinymce editor to edit some content and store the value in a JSON object in a property and using `JSON.parse(JSONObject)` to post the value to server.

In server-side when I decode the JSON data with PHP it doesn't work. Any idea what should be done with new lines entered in the tinymce editor before encoding the data? It works perfectly when I didn't have any newline entered in the tinymce editor.

Comment: define, "didn't work"

Comment: Debugged further and narrow down the issue is that the JSON content is lost when it is posted. It happens in the line brakes which happened inside inside the tinymce edited content. I have copied the JSON data posted from browser at http://jsfiddle.net/EQGR5/ I want to know how to overcome the issue.

Comment: Solve the issue. The issue was with special HTML characters. &nbsp; Used encodeURIComponent(data) before posting the value and it fixed the issue.